# Adding service reference to portable class library

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio

I am making a portable C# class library and I am trying to add a web service reference to my project.

Using VS 2013, I right click on the solution and in my other projects there would be an option to "Add service reference." But in my mobile library project that option does not exist.

Is there something special one needs to do to add a service reference to a mobile library or is it not possible?

See screenshot, there isn't even an option to add a service reference to my project.

[image]

Comment: so in the project / solution are you saying that you do not see any node that says `References` ...?

Comment: I do have 'add reference' but none of those references allow for web services.

Comment: there is an Advanced setting if I am not mistaken that will give you the option to select an existing web service let me look to depict the exact steps..ok do you see one that says add Service Reference..and at the bottom of that Dialog Popup you will see and `Advanced` button.. click on that and select Add Web Reference

Comment: What I am saying is that there is not even an option for "Add service reference". See screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/XwwXZZx.png

Comment: What targets do you have specified in your project file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was having the same problem. Right after creation of a new project of type "Blank App (Xamarin.Forms Shared) in Visual Studio there was no "Add Service Reference" link when I right clicked on PCL. What I did was I just created another PCL and referenced it instead of default one (which I deleted later).
I chose project of type "Class Library (Portable for iOS, Android and Windows)".

[image]

And then I went to project's properties and unselected "Windows Phone 8.1" checkbox.

[image]

And "Add Service Reference" link appeared all over the sudden.

[image]

I am using Visual Stuido 2015 Community Edition (version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2). Hope this will work for you guys too.

Comment: It seems that any PCL template should work that way. The only essential thing is to remove "Windows phone 8.1" (just "phone", not "Windows phone Silverlight") from desired targets.

Comment: but how do you support Windows Phone 8.1 now?

Answer (score 7):

The reason you can't add Service Reference in a Xamarin Forms PCL project can be:

1. Windows Phone 8.1 (not Silverlight). Remove it by going to properties on PCL project and click Change. You might not be able to do it before you remove all your Nuget Packages.
2. Visual Studio crashes when you add the service reference. Remove Xamarin Forms nuget package and Asp.net SignalR. That worked for me. I didn't have Entity Framework Core but that might have to be removed temporarily as well.

Comment: Also unchecked type reuse is required (causing visual studio crash).

Comment: Do you know why this is Fanda?

Answer (score 2):

Add Reference "System.ServiceModel" and can you see "Service Reference"

Comment: Doing this allows you to add the service reference, however, when you then try to compile your project you get compilation errors and a compilation warning about the "System.Xml.XmlElement" type not being supported in portable libraries.

Comment: Here's another SO article that kind of ties in to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301157/portable-class-library-xmlanyelementattribute

Comment: How do i add System.servicemodel

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same situation where the add service reference is missing from the context menu. The most voted answer pointed me to the right direction but I did not create another project. Just rename your packages.config first (maybe to .old). This should overcome the "The selected targets require the project to opt-into NuGet 3.0 support..." error when you uncheck Windows Phone from the targets.

And yes it seems that removing Windows Phone target enables the add service reference context menu on your PCL project.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and I solve this  going to Xamarin portable properties, Library, button Change (Targets) and I  unchecked all Windows Phone Targets