# Add Web Reference In Xamarin PCL

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

-Windows 10

-Visual Studio 2017 Community

I'm trying to follow the instructions in  [this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27044383/adding-service-reference-to-portable-class-library) to remove the Windows 8.1 targeting so I can add a ASMX Web Service reference to my PCL Project.

The Windows Phone 8.1 Shows in my list of targets, however when I open up the `Change` Button to remove it, it does not display the dropdown for Windows Phone 8.1 as shown in the above-mentioned SO Post?

[image]

Comment: [Sorry for the poor english] I had the same need some months ago. Despite all the struggle to get it working, when I finished did it I notice that the webservice classes in PCL project only works in the async pattern, and it wasn't what I want. So I thrown it away and then I've changed to platform specific implementations, using the dependency injection at the PCL project. It worked like a charm! Be aware abou this, =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unload the PCL project. Edit it and change to profile 78. Reload the project and option Add Services is available now.